# Selecting ng-options with key value pair is not working

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have an object like this:

```
"choiceList":[{"1":"cash"},{"2":"credit"}]
```

I want to show this object in a `select` element in which `option` elements display cash and credit. 
I have another variable in which I want to save 1 or 2 if either cash or credit is selected.

HTML:

```
<select name="memoType" ng-model="lookUpValue"> 
    <option value="">--Please Choose--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in list">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
function ControllerA($scope) {    
    $scope.list= {"1" : "Cash" , "2" : "Credit"}; 
 }



<div ng-controller="ControllerA" ng-app>
    Simple options<br/>
    <select ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in list" ng-model="lookUpValue">
</select><br/>
    lookUpValue= {{lookUpValue}}

</div>
```

[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n25ubvp9/2/)

Comment: i tried this it will shown me like this :- [object object]

Comment: @Azad Shaikh Check my demo.See care fully,In ng-option "k as v for (k, v) in list"

Comment: my object is like this :- [{"1":"cash"},{"2":"credit"}]

Comment: mine is array of objects

Comment: <select name="memoType" ng-model="lookUpValue"> <option value="">--Please Choose--</option> <option ng-repeat="choice in list">{{choice[$index+1]}}</option></select>

Comment: this will shown options properly but i am unable to get index of selected option

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your updated question

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="ControllerA" ng-app ng-init="lookUpValue='0'">
    Simple options<br/>
    <select ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in list[0] " ng-model="lookUpValue">
</select><br/>
    lookUpValue = {{lookUpValue}}<br/>     
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function ControllerA($scope) {    
    $scope.list = [{"0":"--Please Choose--","1" : "Cash" , "2" : "Credit"}]; 

 }
```

See complete working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n25ubvp9/6/)